# Remote Code Execution (RCE) Vulnerability: PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

I am tracking info on the RCE vulnerability on PHPMailer.  I've seen that Rev. 5.2.18 has been patched for the vuln.  Does that also apply to later versions as well (e.g., 5.4)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's irrelevant, contained no coding question, should have been directed at project maintainers, not asked as a general question.

Answer (score 0):

Why ask that on here? There is no PHPMailer 5.4; The latest release is 5.2.21, which also contains a mitigation for CVE-2016-10045. You can [read more about these vulnerabilities on the project wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/About-the-CVE-2016-10033-and-CVE-2016-10045-vulnerabilities).